# Using apples inbuild qrscanner inside a website

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner

I was wondering if it is possible to use apples inbuild QR scanner inside a website, because I want to build a inbuild qr scanner for my website and android supports it no problem, but on IOS it is a different story, does anyone know this?